# “Unable to run test .. Unexpected character ('"' ” on Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When testing my rules on the Business Rules service on Bluemix, I get the following error:

> "Unable to run test
>
> Error when extracting the ruleset parameter value from the request.
>   Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate
>   OBJECT entries at [Source:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTInputStream@b79d0b4f; line: 4, column:
>   10]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misconstructed the input parameter (it was missing a comma ',' between the 2 entries "name" and "id"):

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "foo"
        "id": "bar"
    }
}
```

Once I added the comma delimiter I could run the test successfully:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "foo",
        "id": "bar"
    }
}
```